# If $f,g$ are continuous from $X \rightarrow \Bbb R$ where $(X,J)$ is a topology, the set of $x$ where $f(x) \geq g(x)$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology

If $f,g$ are continuous maps from $X \rightarrow \Bbb R$ where $(X,J)$ is a topology, then I wish to show that the set $A$ where $f(x) \geq g(x)$ is closed.

My first thought is to show that $A$ contains its limit points. So if $x$ is a limit point such that every punctured neighborhood of $x$ hits a point in $A$, I don't see how that helps (there would be some $y$ nearby where $f(y) \geq g(y)$ holds).

I need a hint to understand this problem.

Comment: Hint: $f - g$ is continuous and $[0, \infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed (or equivalently, $(-\infty, 0)$ is open).

Comment: @TheoBendit  Ok so since $f-g$ is continuous, the inverse image of a closed set you described is closed, which is equivalent to the set of $x$ where $f(x) \geq g(x)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $p$ is not in $A = \{x \in X: f(x) \ge g(x)\}$.
We will show that $p$ is not a limit point of $A$:

We know that $f(p) < g(p)$ and as these are real numbers, we can find some
$r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(p) < r < g(p)$.
But then note that $U=g^{-1}[(r, +\infty) \cap f^{-1}[(-\infty, r)]$ is an open set of $X$ (here we use continuity of $f$ and $g$ and the fact that open segments are open in the reals) that contains $p$ and such that any $x \in U$ obeys $f(x) < r$ and $g(x) > r$, which ensures that $x \notin A$.

So $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $p$ that does not intersect $A$. So any $p \notin A$ cannot be a limit point of $A$ (or logically equivalent: $A$ contains all its limit points).
$A$ is thus closed.

Comment: Wow. Great! Thanks for the help

Comment: @IntegrateThis glad to help. As an exercise, extend this to all ordered spaces (in the order topology) instead of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note $f−g$ is continuous, and the inverse image of a $[0, \infty]$ (a closed set) is closed, which is equivalent to the set of $x$ where $f(x)≥g(x)$, therefore show that the set $A=\{ x| f(x)≥g(x) \}$ is closed.